Sum that converges to arbitrary $s$
I am just curious about this problem: suppose I know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n = L$ and $a_n>0$ for all $n$. Does there exist a subsequence $\{a_{n_k}\}$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{n_k}=x$ for any $0<x<L$?
I think I can let $n_1$ be the last index such that $a_1+\ldots+a_{n_1}<x$. Then I am thinking about slowly approaching $x$ using $a_{n_2}, a_{n_3}, \ldots$. However, I don't know how to formalize this or whether this is the right approach. Any hints?

Yes. I just fixed it.

To the question, no.  Consider $\frac 12=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac 13\right)^n$.  You can't get any sum strictly between $\frac 16$ and $\frac 13$.  After all, if you include the first term, $\frac 13$, then your sum is at least $\frac 13$ and if you don't include it, the sum is at most $\frac 16$.

If $a_1>\sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty}a_k$ then no number between $a_1$ and $\sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty}a_k$ can be written in this form.

Here it doesn't work for you extracting case. Yet, in similar ideas, you can look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem. Which explores how you can permutate terms of conditionaly convergent (simply but diverge in absolute) series to reach any real number or infinty.
